# Out of a set of data returned grouped by months, only the initial month is returning incorrect data

Tags: sql

I am trying to return data for the last 24 months as of the end of last month.  Only the initial month returns incorrect data, while all the other months are correct.  I believe the issue is in the strBeginDate = section of the code.  Any ideas what would be causing partially returned data for the initial month?  Thank you very much.

```
Sub GetStaticApprovalRates_Slide6()

    Dim strBeginDate
    Dim strEndDate

    strEndDate = Sheets("Instructions").Range("EndDate").Value
    strBeginDate = DateAdd("m", -23, strEndDate) + 1

    Sheets("Slide6Data").Select
```

Comment: you post the question as `SQL` but show no `SQL`

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than that - how are `strEndDate` and `strBeginDate` used?  Does `strBeginDate` need to be the first day of the month?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what's wrong based only on what you posted.  But I do see that you are calculating the start date based on the end date, by only subtracting months.   There is no allowance for days.  So you might be missing some of that first month by not allowing for the early days of that first month.

That is , if end date occurs mid-month, I think your algorithm would cause start date to be mid-month also.  Perhaps missing days 1-x of that first month.

Comment: Robb, your answer would be so much better if you included some code in it.